# how to open the sublime text in git (command tools) to edit the html,js.css.or something else under the window

Tags: git, command-line, window, sublimetext2, edit

Atually I mean that whether we can combine the two tools,

and that is to say, i want to open the sublimetext in git as we use the vim to dev in the git.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git config --global core.editor`

I'm assuming you want Sublime Text on the Mac, so, your command would be something like:

```
git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Sublime\ Text\2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

Comment: Hi, @wldouglas, did that work for you?  I wasn't quite sure from your question if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I just use it under the window and ubuntu,but THANKS ANYWAY